# Can I make an already partitioned USB flash drive bootalble, without reformatting?

Tags: boot, usb

Can I make an already partitioned USB flash drive bootalble, without reformatting?

- 1st partition: 262MB FAT32 which I do not want to touch if I don't have to
- 2nd partition: 3.7GB which I plan to copy an Ubuntu liveCD onto

Will it be bootable then, or must the beginning of the drive contain special data (like MBR on hard drives)?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of happens under Windows, I'm not aware of any utility that will do that under Linux.

But even at that, I don't advice it, because it still may damage you USB drive.  If you want to use it, **Make sure that you have a backup of the data that's on the drive**.

The utility that you need is called [MakeBootable](http://www.megaleecher.net/Make_Bootable_USB). It is a free utility that creates a bootable flash drive without erasing the data.

Answer (score 0):

[live-fat-stick](https://github.com/cyberorg/live-fat-stick) script can do it easily

http://lizards.opensuse.org/2013/02/14/live-usb-gui/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.